# conxion DB en android con MSSQL auth

Tags: java, android-studio, sql-server

Estoy tratando de conectar a una BD desde dispositivo Android, pero la BD esta en MSSQL con windows authentication a travez de una VPN. Descarge al dispositivo la app Sonicwall la cual me conecta a la VPN pero Al correr el proyecto tengo este error:`java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: DB server closed connection.`.
en algunos post he leido que esto no se puede hacer, que solo funciona en windows. Agradesco su tiempo y respuestas a este asunto.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String cn = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip:port/DBname;instance=INSTANCIA_SQL;user=username;password=secret;";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(cn);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from table");
        while (resultSet.next()){
            Log.i("primer campo",resultSet.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Aunque es posible que se puedan hacer ese tipo de conexiones desde un movil a una base de datos "Me consta en MySQL", es muy mala practica conectar un movil a la base directamente, en este caso lo recomendable es generar un servicio que resuelva esa necesidad

Comment: Arnold, definiste los permisos de internet y acceso a la red?